# ruamel.yaml: modify dump() to add extra '-' at the very start

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml library to dump a dictionary into a yaml file. However it does not behave the way I'd like it to.

How could I get:

```
---
- a: 
    - foo: bar
    - bar: foo
```

instead of:

```
a:
    - foo: bar
    - bar: foo
```

with `yaml.dump()`

I'm extracting the data from:

```
data = {
    'a': [
         {'foo':'bar'},
         {'bar':'foo'}
       ]
     }
```

Any other library with the same functionality is open for proposal.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Are you maybe missing a space after the `-`? Because `-foo` is simply the string `-foo`. Creating a sequence entry requires a space after the dash.

Comment: I want to add the `-` before `a:` so it can look like `- a:`. I need it because of another library that needs this format of yaml file so it could be parsed.

Comment: Then please edit your posting including the space. You probably just need to add `[ ... ]` around your data to make it a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is setting `explicit_start = True` on the `YAML` instance. In addition you need to make the top-level a list if you want `- a` instead of just `a` on the second line:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
---
-a:
    -foo: bar
    -bar: foo
"""

data = [{
    'a': [
         {'foo':'bar'},
         {'bar':'foo'}
       ]
     }]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.explicit_start = True
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
---
- a:
  - foo: bar
  - bar: foo
```

Comment: This helped with `---` but I still didn't get the `-a:`. @Anthon

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm getting the data from dictionary. I will edit the post.

Comment: I get the `-a` on the output, because the key is `-a`.

Comment: I edited the post, there was no space between and `-` and `a`

Comment: I had already seen that and updated my answer. Since your example inconsistently indents the root level with 2 positions and the ones below that with 4 (and an offset of 2) you cannot get any closer with normal formatting in ruamel.yaml